# solving linear model with large dataset

Tags: tensorflow, bigdata, linear-regression, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I have a dataset with size ~1T and I want to fit a ridge/lasso model with it. LinearRegressor in tensorflow's canned estimator is great out of box, except that it might be slow. If each pass through the dataset takes 1hour (single machine), it would take a long time if we have multiple iterations, multiple ridge/lasso penalties, multiple response variables, multiple folds for cv etc.

As this seems like a common problem, what are some known ways or existing libraries to handle this?

Comment: You can use distributed training in tensorflow to use more than one machine to process such a large dataset.

Comment: thanks Alex! It is indeed my top choice now, but it is expensive and seems wasteful :(